# "Received widespread adoption": Why the absence of definite article?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

So in the sentence:

> The technology has received widespread adoption.

Why isn't the grammatically correct form be something like:

> The technology has received a widespread adoption.

Or:

> The technology has received widespread adoptions.

?

I've looked through [this grammar guide](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-to-use-articles-before-nouns) and thought the latter two forms make more sense because `adoption` is a countable noun, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to www.learnersdictionary.com, **adoption** can be a countable noun when it means:

> the act or process of adopting someone or something, such as the act
>   or process of adopting a child.
>
> Our lawyer has handled many adoptions.

In your sentence

> The technology has received widespread adoption.

it means:

> the act or process of beginning to use something new or different

therefore it is an uncountable noun.

Comment: Cool, and thanks for mentioning the dictionary! @christina